# Flask application does not execute upon a submit button click on IE, Edge and Chrome (only on Firefox)

Tags: javascript, python, html, google-chrome, flask

I have a Flask application in Python that has a `run()` function in it. The HTML/CSS/JavaScript/JQuery website is rendered properly on all the browsers after I run the app, but my Python script is not executed upon a click of a submit button on any browser other than Firefox (I've tried Internet Explorer, Microsoft Edge and Google Chrome).

Parts of my code that I believe are relevant:

```py
# app.py

from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap

from main.__main__ import main

app = Flask(__name__)
Bootstrap(app)


@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def run():
    print('run function was run!!!')

    file = request.files.get('testers_csv_file')

    if file is None:
        return render_template('home.html')

    file.save('testers_file.csv')

    main('testers_file.csv')  # executes only on Firefox

    return render_template('success.html')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.secret_key = 'some secret key'
    app.config['SESSION_TYPE'] = 'filesystem'
    app.run(debug=True)
```

```html
<!-- home.html -->

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-modal/0.9.1/jquery.modal.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://gist.github.com/Arkni/5df1bd0bb426f766d004927d831d5def#file-additional-methods-min-js"></script>
<!-- EDIT: updated the above link instead of pasting JavaScript code directly as @absolutelydevastated suggested -->

    <script src="jquery-validation-1.15.0/lib/jquery.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet"
          href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.2/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.2/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-modal/0.9.1/jquery.modal.min.css"/>
    <!--    <meta charset="utf-8">-->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="Web tool for assigning test cases to testers and updating trackSpace accordingly">
    <meta name="author" content="Jakub Bober">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T"
          crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>My application</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="static/styles/signin.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body class="text-center">
<div class="container-fluid">
    <form class="form-signin" id="form" method="post" action="/" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <label for="testers_csv_file">Tester's details</label>
        <input type="file" id="testers_csv_file" name="testers_csv_file" class="form-control" accept=".csv" required>
        <br/>
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" id="submitbtn" name="submitbtn" type="submit" value="submit">
            Assign tests
        </button>
    </form>
</div>
<div class="overlay" id="overlay">
    <div id="loading-img"></div>
</div>

<script>
$(".overlay").hide();
$("#sr_vr_versions").show();
$("lido_versions").show();
$("#submitbtn").click(function () {
    if($("#form").valid())
     {
         $(".weird-selects").hide();
         $(".overlay").show();
         event.preventDefault();
     }
});
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

```css
//signin.css

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding-top: 40px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

.form-signin {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 460px;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.form-signin {
  font-weight: 400;
}

.form-signin .form-control {
  position: relative;
  left: 25%;
  width: 50%;
  height: auto;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.form-signin .form-control:focus {
  z-index: 20;
}

#loading-img {
    background: url('loading3.gif') center center no-repeat;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 20;
}

.overlay {
    background: #e9e9e9;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0.9;
}
```

`success.html` contains just a text that the app has run successfully.

As I said, when I launch `app.py` in any browser, I get the `file` field and `submit` button (and the gif image shows up when I click on it). But only on Firefox the `main` function executes and `success.html` shows up after `main` is executed, on other browsers nothing happens and the gif just stays forever.

The console message I get when I launch the app from Firefox:

```
run function was run!!!
127.0.0.1 - - [12/Sep/2019 12:33:06] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [12/Sep/2019 12:33:06] "GET /jquery-validation-1.15.0/lib/jquery.js HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [12/Sep/2019 12:33:06] "GET /jquery-validation-1.15.0/lib/jquery.js HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [12/Sep/2019 12:33:07] "GET /static/styles/loading3.gif HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

and from Chrome:

```
run function was run!!!
127.0.0.1 - - [12/Sep/2019 12:34:19] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [12/Sep/2019 12:34:19] "GET /jquery-validation-1.15.0/lib/jquery.js HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [12/Sep/2019 12:34:19] "GET /jquery-validation-1.15.0/lib/jquery.js HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

So in Chrome less stuff gets rendered, but the `app` runs too.

**BUT** when I click on the `submit` button on Chrome, **NOTHING IS PRINTED IN THE CONSOLE**. Meanwhile on Firefox:

```
run function was run!!!
127.0.0.1 - - [12/Sep/2019 12:35:59] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [12/Sep/2019 12:35:59] "GET /jquery-validation-1.15.0/lib/jquery.js HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [12/Sep/2019 12:35:59] "GET /jquery-validation-1.15.0/lib/jquery.js HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

**I THINK** there is a problem with rendering the templates when the `file` is `None` in the `app.py` script and Firefox somehow deals with it better, but I don't know how to solve this issue. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: If your `jQuery` file is a resource in your project, you need to use the template engine to "render" it in the page. I suggest that you change your `jQuery` validation script to download from an online source instead. That said, your "main" function always gets executed on page load. However, it never (and will never) gets called again. I don't think your HTML page sends any request that'll trigger the function to render `success.html`. You only fetch the GIF file from your static resources.

Comment: @absolutelydevastated I think I see what you mean, but then the `main` function would not be executed on Firefox either. Meanwhile, on Firefox after clicking on the submit button the `main` function starts executing (the GIF image shows up) and after a few seconds (when it executes), `success.html` is properly rendered on my current Firefox tab (saying 'Tests assigned successfully!' and showing the actual tests assigned after executing `main`).

Comment: Okay, I see the `post` in your form now. It might then be an issue with the `event` variable which may or may not be evaluated properly.